# Connecting a DVR Tuner to a Plex Server in Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, plex

is there a way to connect a dvr tuner to a Plex Server hosted in Hyper-V?

I have searched but could not find a Question about this topic.

My build is a Win22 Datacenter Server running Plex in Hyper-V. A Hauppauge dualHD is connected to the Win22 Datacenter Server via USB.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Current Answer

I'm updating my answer as I didn't realize it was a tuner and not a DVR box connected to your TV.
From what I'm seeing online, your best bets are:

- use [Enhanced Session Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/enhanced-session-mode) to connect the device over RDP (which only supports some devices)
- use a third-party tool such as [Donglify](https://www.donglify.net/) (this is from results on Google. Buy at your own digression) to allow USB passthrough
- use a Type 2 hypervisor ([VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org), [VMware](https://www.vmware.com/)) to run your instance of Plex instead
- run Plex outside of Hyper-V on the same system with a sandboxed user
- run Plex on another device entirely, [such as a Raspberry Pi](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-plex-server/).

I can't help with the first, as it requires [some gpedit.msc magic I cannot do,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/355467/remotef-to-redirect-usb-web-cam-into-hyper-v-vm-wi.html) or second as I have never used one.
3rd option will reduce program speeds which may cause slowdown if multiple people stream at once.
4th option is my personal recommendation, as you bypass the need to use a hypervisor entirely and keep on the same device.
5th is only good if you use a USB-based drive and have a decent bit of experience with Linux.

---

### Old Answer

Kept for the sake of archival.

You'll want to use Powershell and the `Add-NetNatStaticMapping` cmdlet to allow inbound connections to the Hyper-V server. This will need a vNAT adapter set up. See the linked blog post (not mine) if you need help with that, too.
Assuming the vEthernet connection has an internal IP of `192.168.10.2` and a NAT network name of `NATSwitch`, with Plex on the default port of `32400`:

```
Add-NetNatStaticMapping -ExternalIPAddress "0.0.0.0/24" -ExternalPort 32400 -Protocol TCP -InternalIPAddress "192.168.10.2" -InternalPort 32400 -NatName NATNetwork
```

You will most likely need to replace the internal IP, port, and NAT name.
*After this is set up, you'll need to point your DVR to the IP of the Windows Server box.*

Sites referenced:
[Plex support page on ports to forward](https://support.plex.tv/articles/201543147-what-network-ports-do-i-need-to-allow-through-my-firewall/)
[A GitHub user's blog, specifically a post on port forwarding](https://tewarid.github.io/2019/06/26/port-forwarding-in-hyper-v.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer, i will try it out and report back to you.

Comment: No problem. Make sure to comment on this once you've tried it.

Comment: Sorry for my maybe dull question, but im relativly new to Hyper V.Would it not be easier to get the usb device ( Hauppauge dualHD ) from the Win22 Server to be accessable for the Plex Hyper-V VM on that same Server?

Comment: No worries, that was my bad. I've updated my answer as I misread your question. You should look at what I have to say (I recommend the 4th option).
Also, this question is probably more fit for PowerUser or ServerFault, but I'm not flagging it. Someone else might, though. Have a nice rest of your day.

Comment: Thanks for the options. :) i think i will install a second plex server on a Raspberry pi only for the Live TV. Than i can use the easy and expandable functions of Hyper-V and can use the Live TV without problems. :)

Comment: I have installed the Plex Server on the Win22 Server and use the DVR direct on the Server USB. Works perfect. :)